# How can I get windows server 2008 to alert people when they kick someone off via remote desktop?

Tags: windows-server-2008

We only have a maximum of two users for our windows server 2003, so we use them between us. However if one of us logs on while another is using it, I would like a message to be displayed as a warning or alert, because presently there is no indication you have kicked someone off.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you have a volume licencing agreement, Terminal Services licencing isn't that expensive. I have one server designated a "Admin" server which has the manament consoles for virtually all of the site services then all my Administrators use this one server for Administration tasks.

Comment: We don't have a volume licensing agreement, and its our only server. We're in a small company.

Comment: Only the one server? If you have terminal services manager running it should tell you when someone else is logged in, or it'll tell you that your server has the maximum number of users logged in already and not allow you to log in. At least that's on our system, unless the configuration we have isn't the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to msg.exe to the user@server before you log on?

What you need, as far as I can see, is

1. a system manage the resource
   (limited logons)
2. a system to communicate (i.e. chat/messaging or similar)

Answer (score 1):

If you know any scripting, you could do a logon script that looks for the other session and does a popup if someone else is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You can also log on with:

mstsc -v:servername.com -console

to log onto the console for a total of 3 sessions.

By default, the system should give an error that the maximium number of connections have been reached and you cannot connect. Not just kick off another user.

Comment: I'm assuming they're all using the same username to connect, hence there's no warning regarding kicking another user off as that's not what's happening. It's the same username connecting from another workstation. Windows has no way to know that a different human being is using the same username.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a warning, unless you share accounts. The solution then, is never to share accounts ^^

Comment: Not fantastically helpful, unless you want to shed out a few thousand for a license ;o

Comment: License for what? You have unlicensed domain users? Domain admin accounts shouldn't consume any CALs afaik?